# Why do random characters get dropped during randomization?

Tags: c#, random

EDIT: Apparently my first attempt at asking the question was not clear enough and they closed it. I thought I was pretty clear:
*why does the `Random()` method nor properly randomize a string?*

I'll preface this with I'm new to C#. This is SUPER simple in PowerShell, but I want to understand how to do it in C#. Here's the code, I'll explain what's not working.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lena = 10; 
            string randomLowercase = Randomize("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",lena);
            
            var lenb =2;
            string randomUppercase = Randomize("ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA", lenb);

            var lenc = 2;
            string randomNumbers = Randomize("0123456789", lenc);

            var lend = 2;
            string randomSpecChar = Randomize("!%&()?}][{@*", lend);

            string randomWord = randomLowercase + randomUppercase + randomNumbers + randomSpecChar;
            string randomPassword = Randomize(randomWord, randomWord.Length);

            Console.Write("Random Lowercase: {0}\nRandom Uppercase: {1}\nRandom Numbers: {2}\nRandom Special Characters: {3}\n", randomLowercase, randomUppercase, randomNumbers, randomSpecChar);
            
            Console.Write("\nRandom Word Length: {0}\nRandom Word: {1}\n", randomWord.Length, randomWord);
            Console.Write("\nRandom Password: {0}", randomPassword);
            
            Console.Read();
        }

       static string Randomize(string text, int len)
        {
            var chars = text;
            var stringChars = new char[len];
            var random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i<stringChars.Length; i++)
            {
                stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }

            var output = new String(stringChars);
            return output;
        }
    }
```

This is what it outputs:

```
Random Lowercase: kmrdmcqxlh
Random Uppercase: PN
Random Numbers: 34
Random Special Characters: )?

Random Word Length: 16
Random Word: kmrdmcqxlhPN34)?

Random Password: qxPrxmP)qmml43Pl
```

The jumble-up of the 16 characters works - I get 'kmrdmcqxlhPN34)?'. But the last part breaks something. It drops one of the special characters - the '?', adds an extra 'P' and some other things.

The random word is fine - what could cause the error in the Randomize method? I'm thinking it's leftover values maybe? Should I reset any variables when I exit the method?

Comment: Yea, I think if you want to gaurantee there's at least one upper case, one lower case and one special character, then you can't randomize `randomWord` in the end.  Maybe insert each group in a random spot instead?

Comment: I think what you want to do is shuffle after you've selected the character set, `randomWord`. This is not what you are doing. Look up Fisher-Yates shuffle for an efficient algorithm.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You have a method to select `len` random characters from an input string `text`. So that's what it does when you call it passing the combined string. There's no reason to believe that it will always select the same values. Besides that, the whole approach to password generation is flawed. The point of a strong password is to make it hard to predict what characters will be in it, as well as where those characters are. If you shuffle the final string, that can help with the second part, but by limiting the count of specific types of characters, the first breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

random digits can be the same, in this case you get duplicate symbols. May be you need shuffle method like this. It's returned string contains the same characters in random order

```
static string Shuffle(string s)
{
   Random rand = new Random();
   var chars = s.ToCharArray();
   for (int i = chars.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
   {
      int j = rand.Next(i);
      (chars[i], chars[j]) = (chars[j], chars[i]);
   }
 
   return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: Daniela, can you post a link to documentation for the syntax you're using in this line? `(chars[i], chars[j]) = (chars[j], chars[i]);`  That looks so weird to my old-school brain...what the?

Comment: @Idle_Mind  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct

Answer (score 2):

For the last part, once you've got all the pieces put together into "randomWord", you need to create a different method that simply SHUFFLES the existing letters.

Maybe something like:

```
private static Random R = new Random();

private static string ShuffleString(string text)
{
    return new string(text.ToCharArray().
        OrderBy(c => R.NextDouble()).ToArray());
}
```

Example:

```
string a = "Hello World!";
string b = ShuffleString(a);
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Comment: Note that this answer has the creation of the `Random` instance outside any function in a static variable (with the initialization effectively in the class's static constructor).  All of your randomization should use that same static `Random` instance.  In the code you show in your question, you have `var random = new Random();` in the function that randomizes things.  Don't do that - create one `Random` instance and use it over and over